# Google App Engine Datanucleus enhencer

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus, maven-gae-plugin

I have following class as superclass

```
@Entity
@MappedSuperclass
public class Location implements LocationCapable {

    @Basic
    private Double latitude;

    @Basic
    private Double longitude;

    @Basic
    private List<String> geocells;

    @PrePersist
    @Transient
    private void generateGeoCells() {
        geocells = GeocellManager.generateGeoCell(getLocation());
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    @Override
    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    public Point getLocation() {
        return new Point(latitude, longitude);
    }

    @Override
    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getKeyString() {
        return latitude + ":" + longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getGeocells() {
        return geocells;
    }

    public void setGeocells(List<String> geocells) {
        this.geocells = geocells;
    }

}
```

And another one which inherits from this

But when I try to run JUnit test I got this

```
Caused by: org.datanucleus.metadata.InvalidMetaDataException: Class Location has application-identity and no objectid-class specified yet has 0 primary key fields. Unable to use SingleFieldIdentity.
at org.datanucleus.metadata.AbstractClassMetaData.determineObjectIdClass(AbstractClassMetaData.java:1032)
at org.datanucleus.metadata.ClassMetaData.populate(ClassMetaData.java:205)
at org.datanucleus.metadata.AbstractClassMetaData.validateSuperClass(AbstractClassMetaData.java:720)
at org.datanucleus.metadata.AbstractClassMetaData.determineSuperClassName(AbstractClassMetaData.java:642)
at org.datanucleus.metadata.ClassMetaData.populate(ClassMetaData.java:193)
at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager$1.run(MetaDataManager.java:2317)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.populateAbstractClassMetaData(MetaDataManager.java:2311)
at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.populateFileMetaData(MetaDataManager.java:2148)
at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.initialiseFileMetaDataForUse(MetaDataManager.java:864)
at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadPersistenceUnit(MetaDataManager.java:794)
at org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.initialisePMF(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:488)
at org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:355)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastoreEntityManagerFactory.<init>(DatastoreEntityManagerFactory.java:63)
at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastorePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(DatastorePersistenceProvider.java:35)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createFactory(Persistence.java:172)
... 67 more
```

Also I've tried to add in supperclass the key field annotated with @Id but it gives no result for me

Answer (score 2):

You have to have an @Id field, as the message says.

Comment: ok, sorry here is my direct question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760061/gae-datanucleus-jpa-problem-with-embedded

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was some problem with enhancing or eclipse plugin, no metter after restart of IDE the problem dessapiared. But only this problem with ID. Actually I've faced with another very strange problem related to embedded entities. I have following domain model:

```
@Entity
public class City {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
    @Basic
    private String name;
    // Entity won't persist if location is not null, requires to persist with
    // further update
    @Embedded
    // @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) it works the same when I add or remove this line
    private Location location;

    /* getters and setters */
} 

@Embeddable
public class Location implements LocationCapable {
    @Basic
    @NotNull
    private Double latitude;
    @Basic
    @NotNull
    private Double longitude;
    @Basic
    private List<String> geocells;

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

To test it I have following JUnit test case:

```
    @Test
    public void testSave() throws Exception {
        City city = new City("testCity1", new Location(1d, 1d));
        cityDao.persist(city);
        assertNotNull(city.getId());
    }
```

`cityDao.persist(city)` does simply `jpaTemplate.persist(object);`

And at when I try to persist this entity I got following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: out of field index :-1
    at com.myproject.model.Location.jdoProvideField(Location.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.provideField(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:2585)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.provideField(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:2555)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.CollectionMapping.postInsert(CollectionMapping.java:91)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.EmbeddedPCMapping.postInsert(EmbeddedPCMapping.java:104)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager.runPostInsertMappingCallbacks(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:217)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager.access$200(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:48)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager$1.apply(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:116)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager.storeRelations(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:81)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreFieldManager.storeRelations(DatastoreFieldManager.java:955)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.storeRelations(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:546)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertPostProcess(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:304)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjects(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:256)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:240)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3185)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.flush(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:4513)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flushInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2814)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flush(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2754)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.preCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2893)
    at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.internalPreCommit(TransactionImpl.java:369)
    at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:256)
    at org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:104)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastoreEntityTransactionImpl.commit(DatastoreEntityTransactionImpl.java:55)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
    ... 41 more
```